# \textsc for citations with page numbers

Tags: cross-referencing, citing, multiple-citations

When citing a reference directly in the body text, I use the following:

```
\textsc{\citet[p. 2 ff.]{someSource}}
```

However, in the produced .pdf the indications "p." and "ff." are affected by \textsc as well. Please see the following as an example.

[image]

Is there any chance to avoid \textsc taking effect on the indications "p." and "ff."?

Thank you!

Comment: It's recommended that you include a minimal working example (See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means.) e.g. where does the command `citet` come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `natbib`, you can use `\textnormal` in the optional argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\textsc{\citet[p. 2 ff.]{misc-full}}

\textsc{\citet[\textnormal{p. 2 ff.}]{misc-full}}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

[image]